# How to insert custom colormap in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm plotting a bunch of triangles using a for loop and the fill3 command as shown below. I want to do something like this example where a Z-range corresponds to a particular color.

[image: Example of what I want]

Right now, I'm using fill3(x,y,z,'r') since I'm not really sure what else to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the color at each vertex and interpolate between them. You can also create solid color polygons by setting the color at each vertex to be the same.

From the matlab documentation

> fill3(X,Y,Z,C) fills three-dimensional polygons. X, Y, and Z triplets specify the polygon vertices. If X, Y, or Z is a matrix, fill3 creates n polygons, where n is the number of columns in the matrix. fill3 closes the polygons by connecting the last vertex to the first when necessary.
>
> C specifies color, where C is a vector or matrix of indices into the current colormap. If C is a row vector, length(C) must equal size(X,2) and size(Y,2); if C is a column vector, length(C) must equal size(X,1) and size(Y,1).

An example for creating a polygon, whose colors at each vertex are proportional to the Z coordinate:

```
X = [0 1 1];
Y = [1 1 0];
Z = [0 0.5 1];
C = [Z(1)/max(Z);
    Z(2)/max(Z);
    Z(3)/max(Z)];
fill3(X,Y,Z,C);
%optional
colormap(hot);
```